# How to make loop that continues until nothing is happening?

Tags: java, while-loop

Im writing a kind of shopping list using JLabels and i have a button that can remove items from the list. I wrote some code to make it so the gaps close and all of the JLabels move up until all space is filled. The problem is i have to press a button for every JLabel to move. I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to use a while loop to run the code in a loop until nothing is happening ( which would mean that there are no gaps and everything is at the top)

```
String remove1 = ListSlot1.getText();
String remove2 = ListSlot2.getText();
String remove3 = ListSlot3.getText();

if(remove1=="")
{
ListSlot1.setText(ListSlot2.getText());
ListSlot2.setText("");
}
if(remove2=="")
{
ListSlot2.setText(ListSlot3.getText());
ListSlot3.setText("");
}
if(remove3=="")
{
ListSlot3.setText(ListSlot4.getText());
ListSlot4.setText("");
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure exactly what you're trying to do, but perhaps what you want to use instead is a JList. Consider clarifying your problem.

Comment: You should be using list controls like `JList` to manage actual lists, not emulate them by drawing a bunch of labels and manually moving them around. *Do not re-invent the wheel.*

Comment: I dont know how to run a while where it stops when nothing is changing. My loops just keep replacing "" with "" and it does it forever and i dont know how to stop it

Answer (score 1):

First `remove3==""` is not how `String` comparison in Java is done.

You could use

```
if (remove3 == null || remove3.trim().isEmpty()) {...}
```

or

```
if (remove3 == null || remove3.trim().equals("")) {...}
```

instead...

Secondly, you should make use a `JList` instead.  Take a look at [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean changed = false;
do {
  do stuff;
  if (something has changed) { 
     changed = true;
  }
} while (changed);
```